# Fancybox and Cloudzoom to zoom a rotated image

Tags: javascript, php, image

I am admittedly new to this but I have a working Fancybox application and wish to add the ability to zoom into the images,  I have done so but occasionally the images require Fancybox rotation to be right side up.  When the zoom hover is used, the zoomed image is that of the original non-rotated image.  I'm guessing it's because I tell CloudZoom to use .fancybox-image.

Here's my fancybox:

$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

```
            closeBtn  : true,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,                
            autoDimension : true,
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type: 'Over'
                },
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 75,
                    height : 75
                },
                buttons : {
                tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul><li><a class="btnRotateL" title="left" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnRotateR" title="right" href="javascript:;"></a></li></ul></div>',
                    beforeShow: function (opts, obj) {
                    }
                }, // buttons
            },
                maxWidth: 712,
                maxHeight:968,
                afterShow: function(){
                    var $image = $('.fancybox-image');
                    $image.CloudZoom({zoomPosition:'inside', zoomOffsetX:0});
                },
                beforeLoad: function(){
                    var $image = $('.fancybox-image');
                    if ($image.data('CloudZoom')) $image.data('CloudZoom').destroy();
                },
                beforeClose: function(){
                    var $image = $('.fancybox-image');
                    if ($image.data('CloudZoom')) $image.data('CloudZoom').destroy();
                }
            });
```

Do you know of a way to tell CloudZoom to use the image as currently displayed by Fancybox so that a rotated image can be zoomed?